# can't get negated conditional if to work

Tags: bash, if-statement

for some obvious reason I am unable to discern why my conditional 'if' statements in the following bash snippet don't work:

```
artist=$(audtool --current-song-tuple-data artist|sed -r 's/^[ ]*(.*)[ ]*$/\1/') ; echo "\$artist: $artist"
album=$(audtool --current-song-tuple-data album|sed -r 's/^[ ]*(.*)[ ]*$/\1/') ; echo "\$album: $album"

#need to isolate the three sections of info data available from '--current-song' option; they are 'artist', 'album-title' and 'song-title', except they are never strictly in the same order for all songs. Therfore by isolating them, and eliminating the 'artist' and 'album-title' based on their own vars it can be more certain the remaining var is the 'song-title'
t1=$(audtool --current-song|sed -r 's/^([^-]*)[ ]*-.*$/\1/'|sed -r 's/^[ ]*(.*)[ ]*$/\1/') ; echo "\$t1: ${t1}"
t2=$(audtool --current-song|sed -r 's/^[^-]*-[ ]*([^-]*)[ ]*-.*$/\1/'|sed -r 's/^[ ]*(.*)[ ]*$/\1/') ; echo "\$t2: ${t2}"
t3=$(audtool --current-song|sed -r 's/^[^-]*-[^-]*-[ ]*(.*)[ ]*$/\1/'|sed -r 's/^[ ]*(.*)[ ]*$/\1/') ; echo "\$t3: ${t3}"
if [[ "$t1" != "$artist" && "$t1" != "$album" ]] ; then     #'if' 
        title="$t1"
elif [[ "$t2" != "$artist" && "$t2" != "$album" ]] ; then       #'if'
        title="$t2"
elif [[ "$t3" != "$artist" && "$t3" != "$album" ]] ; then       #'if'
        title="$t3"
fi

echo "\$title: ${title}"
```

Terminal output:

```
$artist: Van Halen
$album: Best Of Volume 1
$t1: Van Halen 
$t2: Best Of Volume 1 
$t3: Unchained
$title: Van Halen
```

The intention is to isolate the name of the current song being played by audacious, without listing the artist and album-title. But no matter what, var `$title` always ends up == var `$artist`, meaning the negated conditionals are not working.

I actually even split the && part of the 'if' statements into nested if's which made no difference. Var `$title` still managed to == var `$artist`. As expected, using `if [[ ! "$t1" == "$artist" && ! "$t1" == "$album" ]] ; then` also makes no difference.

So I am stumped why the 'if' statements are failing to disqualify vars `$artist` and `$album` from equalling (and so being echoed) as var `$title`. If anyone can help point out what I am sure is an obvious oversight I would appreciate the help.

Comment: What are the values of all the variables?

Comment: The first step in debugging any shell script is to put `set -x` at the beginning, so you can see all the statements with the variables filled in.

Comment: Also, watch out for invisible characters (nonprinting characters, spaces at the end of variables, etc). Try printing the variables with e.g. `echo "\$title: '${title}'" | cat -vt` to make them visible.

Comment: funny-sad I have never used the `set -x` option in my scripts. Very useful. Thanks for that. I see now there was a space being added, er not removed from the end of the three vars `$t1`, `$t2` and `$t3` even though I though I implemented 'sed' to remove all spurious spaces at the beginning and end of var assignments. Oh well, works now, thanks for the great, but probably pretty obvious help.

Comment: You need to dump `t1`, `t2`, `t3` and see what they contain. Reason, the only way `title` is assigned is if one of your conditionals test true. Otherwise `title` should remained undefined unless initialized earlier in your code.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up. Its only if you knwo about `set -x` and don't use it, are you doing something ... err ..., non-optimal;-) . Interesting code. +1 for trying to solve your own problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have audtool configured in my system. So i assumed the variable values as you can see below. But i also modified the if checks a bit. If this doesn't work, probably you would be having some extra characters (space or tab etc..) in the variable values

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat ff
#!/bin/bash

artist="Van Halen"
album="Best Of Volume 1"
t1="Van Halen"
t2="Best Of Volume 1"
t3="Unchained"

echo "\$artist: ${artist}"
echo "\$album: ${album}"
echo "\$t1: ${t1}"
echo "\$t2: ${t2}"
echo "\$t3: ${t3}"

if [ "$t1" != "$artist" ] && [ "$t1" != "$album" ]
then
    title="$t1"
elif [ "$t2" != "$artist" ] && [ "$t2" != "$album" ]
then
    title="$t2"
elif [ "$t3" != "$artist" ] && [ "$t3" != "$album" ]
then
    title="$t3"
fi

echo "\$title: ${title}"
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ ./ff
$artist: Van Halen
$album: Best Of Volume 1
$t1: Van Halen
$t2: Best Of Volume 1
$t3: Unchained
$title: Unchained
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$
```